# Cannot get my if statement inside an 'app.post' function to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In the project/web app I am working on, a user can create a new post. Text is required in the post they create, and a photo is optional.

I wish the relevant app.post statement to perform different things depending on whether a picture was included with the post or not. This is my code:

```
app.post('/posts/store', async(req,res)=>{
    
        if(req.files.image===null){
      await BlogPost.create({...req.body,userid:req.session.userId});
    res.redirect('/') 
          }

       else {
    let image = req.files.image;
    image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, "public/img",image.name),async(error)=>{
    await BlogPost.create({...req.body, image:"/img/"+image.name, userid:req.session.userId});
    res.redirect('/') 
    });
   };
})
```

If no image has been included with the post, then there should be no such value as req.files.image. My idea was to have an 'if statement' to check if this value exists, and if it didn't then the relevant logic would be followed so that the post could be posted. Different logic is required if an image is included, which is covered by the else statement.

I have tried variations of "if(req.files.image===null)" but nothing works. I get the error message 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null'.

However, code does work if a picture is uploaded (code skips first 'if' and goes to 'else' instructions). Code also works if I replace 'req.files.image===null' with an obviously truthy statement, and I then upload a blog post without a photo. With this, I think I have at least pinpointed where the mistake lies - in the 'if(req.files.image===null)' line of code  -rather than anywhere else in the code, but still I cannot work out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using any middleware?

> In Express 4, req.files is no longer available on the req object by default. To access uploaded files on the req.files object, use multipart-handling middleware like busboy, multer, formidable, multiparty, connect-multiparty, or pez. (https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req)

It seems like `req.files` is null.
Try

```
if(!req.files || !req.files.image) {
  // req.files.image == null
} else {
  // req.files.image != null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using multer (or a similar) lib to handle the form-data upload with a file. Those libs usually only populate the `req.files` field if a file was given. If not it will be `undefined`. You should extend your check and see if `req.files` exists at all, e.g:

```
if(!req.files || req.files.image === null) {
  await BlogPost.create({...req.body,userid:req.session.userId});
  res.redirect('/') 
}
```